# Eclipse RCP Image Application: How Do I Lay Out My Images?

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, composite, scrolledcomposite

I have an Eclipse plugin that displays a view.  What I want to do is display n images in the view in a single row with a centered label under each image.  I want to view to be scrollable. 
**I also want each image to be re-sized when the dimensions of the view (ScrolledComposite? Composite?) change so it utilizes the available vertical and horizontal client area.**

I have implemented the following in the createViewPart method (declarations and error checking has been omitted):

```
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        ScrolledComposite myScrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(parent, 
        SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

        myComposite = new Composite(myScrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);

        myScrolledComposite.setContent(myComposite);
    }
```

**What's the best approach from this point forward?**

1. **Should I subclass Composite and have that class draw a given image on itself and center a label under the image?**
2. **What layout manager should I use to center the label under the image?**
3. **Should the "parent" parameter of my subclass be "myComposite"?**
4. **Which layout manager should I use with "myComposite"?**
5. **When it comes to resizing the images, do I calculate the available width and height by using the getBounds of "myComposite" - my subclassed composite's getBounds?**

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the [Gallery widget provided by the Eclipse Nebula project](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/gallery/gallery.php), maybe you can use it or at least get some ideas from how they implemented it.

Comment: I did check out the Gallery Widget.  It was just what I needed.  Developers using SWT Widgets should definitely check out the Gallery Widget and the other Widgets that make up the Eclipse Nebula project.